# rebuilding raid array (rocket raid 1740)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, raid, administrator, raid-5

so my rocketraid 1740 controller has 4 connectors .. 
i set it up with raid 5.

**drive on port 4 failed, but it comes back online after computer reboots. array saw this, and started to rebuild the faulty drive.**

i replaced it with new one.

i do not see a way to rebuild the array (in rocket raid bios screen the new drive was showing up as "new", but it would not let me add it as a spare)

in windows web based admin panel, i was able to initialize the new drive, and add it as a spare, but the array is showing as "disabled" and still no option to rebuild..

after rebooting, in raid bios screen, i see the drives as:

```
1-1: WD500AAKS 500 configured 
1-2: WD500AAKS 500 configured 
1-3: WD500AAKS 500 configured 
1-4: WD500AAKS 500 configured (Spare)
```

-

but array is still "disabled" .. and when i view the array, the 4th drive (new one) is showing up as "missing" in the array, but in the devices it is showing as configured(spare)

when i plug in the old faulty drive, it goes back to "critical" state and **automatically continues** rebuilding....  but the drive fails shortly into it and array goes into disabled state..

i am thinking that now that the rebuild started, the remaining 3 drives are not capable to rebuild onto the new drive ?

UPDATE

little by little i am rebuilding the bad drive (it usually works for few hours after rebooting). Hopefully once i get to 100% i will be able to swap in the spare.

> ```
> RAID5: never again
> ```

UPDATE

rebuild of "bad" drive finally finished and i was able to plug in the good drive. 
to my horror.. 2% into rebuilding the good drive, my raid controller started beeping and the 4th drive disappeared! So possibly it's the raid controller that is bad ?!

looks like the only thing i can do now, is get another nas and back up my data using RAID 1

Comment: "Automatic detect drive to rebuild degraded RAID"....http://www.highpoint-tech.cn/USA/rr1740.htm

Comment: Needs to be marked as a spare, see the user manual on the link I posted above.

Comment: it is set to automatic, and new drive is marked as spare.

Comment: new drive keeps showing up as missing in the array setup.. even though it shows as configured (spare) in the device setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was right in my assumptions that the array already started re-building using the bad drive, and i had to wait it out.

after it was done, i plugged in the new drive and it worked.

to my dismay however, after it rebuilt the good drive, it failed again.. so it looks like the controller is at fault.

Raid 5: never again.